# Why are these two projective schemes isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

From Ravi Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, exercise 7.4.C: Let $R = k[x, y, z]/(xz, yz, z^2)$. Show that $\operatorname{Proj} R \cong \mathbb{P}_k^1$ (as schemes).

My thought was to induce a map of schemes via the ring morphism $\phi: R \rightarrow k[s, t]$, with $x \mapsto s, \; y \mapsto t, \; z \mapsto 0$. But I don't know how to show that this induces an isomorphism of schemes. In particular, in $\operatorname{Proj} R$ the two ideals $(x + y)$ and $(x + y + z)$ (for example) are different, which doesn't seem to have a counterpart in $\mathbb{P}_k^1$.

Edit: It's been suggested that we can check this locally. To check locally, define $\alpha:k[s,t]→R$
by $s,t↦x,y$. This induces $\pi:\operatorname{Proj}R→\mathbb{P}_1^k$
such that $\pi^{-1}(D(s))=D(x)$
and $\pi^{-1}(D(t))=D(y)$. I can see that $\pi$
gives a bijection on each of these open sets, but I can't see that it gives isomorphisms of schemes: for example, taking $\varphi:\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj}R}→\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_1^k}$
induced by $\alpha$
, we get $\varphi(D(s)):k[\frac{t}{s}]→k[\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}]$
, which is not an isomorphism. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Do you know that you can check that this map is an isomorphism locally? (One small formatting tip: `$\operatorname{Proj}$` produces $\operatorname{Proj}$, which displays a little better than what you had before. I've made the change for you this time.)

Comment: One can have nonisomorphic rings $R$ and $S$ which give rise to the same $Proj$ (an exercise in Hartshorne II.5 gives an example I think). In this case, you should check this locally.

Comment: I wouldn't even check this locally, I am pretty sure Vakil shows that taking a subring of a graded ring consisting of the graded pieces with indices multiples of some $d>1$ doesn't change the $\operatorname{Proj}$. In this case if you do this (this is called taking the Veronese subalgebra) you get something familiar.

Comment: To check locally, define $\alpha: k[s, t] \rightarrow R$ by $s, t \mapsto x, y$. This induces $\pi: \operatorname{Proj} R \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^1$ such that $\pi^{-1}(D(s)) = D(x)$ and $\pi^{-1}(D(t)) = D(y)$. I can see that $\pi$ gives a bijection on each of these open sets, but I can't see that it gives isomorphisms of schemes: for example, taking $\phi: \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj} R} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}$ induced by $\alpha$, we get $\phi(D(s)): k[\frac{t}{s}] \rightarrow k[\frac{y}{x}, \frac{z}{x}]$, which is not an isomorphism. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Please put that work in your question with an [edit]. (Yes, you've made a small mistake there, I'll write an answer once you've put your work in the question.)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with checking locally, but you have made a small error in calculating the sections of $\operatorname{Proj} R$ on the open sets $D(x)$ and $D(y)$. Recall that $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj} R}(D(x))\cong R_{(x)}$, the homogeneous localization of $R$ at the element $x$. In other words, this is $(R_x)_0$, the degree-zero portion of the graded ring $R_x$. This is $$k\left[\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}\right]/\left(\frac{z}{x},\frac{yz}{x^2},\frac{z^2}{x^2}\right)\cong k\left[\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}\right]/\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\cong k\left[\frac{y}{x}\right]$$ and indeed the map of sections here is an isomorphism, identifying $\frac{y}{x}$ and $\frac{t}{s}$.

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, one may use the fact that if $S=\bigoplus_n S_n$ is a graded ring, the Veronese subring $S^{(d)}=\bigoplus_n S_{nd}$ has the same Proj. In this case, since $R=k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)$ has $R_d\cong k[x,y]_d$ for any $d\neq 1$, then we can use this fact twice to obtain the claim.